# How to deal with "minor tags"?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

We've got a lot of tags which, in my opinion, do not make much sense. To give some examples:

- **app-specific tags for "minor apps"**, e.g. [tunein-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tunein-radio) (x1), [repligo](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repligo) (x1). I fully go with tags for "major apps" which are widely used (good examples here include [google-maps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) (x80) or [google-play-store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store) (x538). But the playstore holds over half a million apps -- we cannot provide a tag for each of them.
- **question-specific tags** applying to only one (or very few) very specific questions, as e.g. [zipaligned](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zipaligned) (x1)

In my opinion, those tags are not very helpful -- but rather make tag-maintenance more difficult. So we might better...

1. discourage users from creating such (sure, rep already does so -- but our better-rep'd members should be aware of this and not simply jump-in when a questioner mentions "...I unfortunately lack the rep to create this tag..."
2. check whether we should "orphan" some of those tags, so the auto-purge cleans them up.

**EDIT:** MSO mentions some [auto-cleaning task](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) running monthly and cleaning up single-used tags from questions aged 6+ months, so this does part of the job. So let me refine my question to: *What should we do when we just stumble-upon such an occurence where the question is, say, only 3+ months old, but the fact as such is clear?*

Note also this quote from the linked MSO question:

> Any tags not currently in use, or that happen to get orphaned through unusual means (rollback, merge, etc), are removed every 24 hours by a background process.

Another still remaining question is whether those two tasks apply to all stacks, as the answer just mentions 4 of them.

Comment: Tags with only one question should be cleaned up automatically [after 6 months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/154510). I agree that users with tag creation privileges should think hard when creating one, though.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I.e., you're for the 2nd option of orphaning low-usage tags? I'm for this option (if the tag is not in much use, then it's a low risk to just orphan it and hope noone uses it in the meantime)

Comment: @ce4 There's nothing wrong with low-usage tags in general (although low usage may hint at some other problem with a tag).  We should removed useless tags and keep/add useful ones.

Comment: I'd say if a tag stands with only one attached Q for 6 months or longer, this fact speaks for itself. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: No.  It could just as easily mean that the tag should be more widely applied but hasn't been -- failure to use tags appropriately goes both ways.

Comment: Oh -- good one, tnx. Guess you don't mind I take that hint up to the question (to make it easier to spot). Remains the Q whether we should take sone action if stumbling upon such a tag on a just, say, 4 month old Q -- or rather wait for the auto-cleaner to come around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think we should jump the gun on the tag cleanup process.

While I can't find any examples at the moment, on multiple occasions I've run across a question where it is the only question for a tag and was able to find a minimum of two or three other questions that could be so tagged.

Comment: While that might apply to many a tag, shouldn't we still at least discourage from creating "a tag for each app"? I'd say it would even make sense to have a popup (or the like) appearing when creating a new tag, with a kind of Windows "are you sure" plus the appropriate hint. Hm, not that anyone would read it, I guess...

Comment: I made the same experience as Al and see no problem with minor tags either. If the cleanup scripts deals with them fine, if not then there is a reason for them to exist. I also see no problem with app specific tags, IMHO that's better then a whole 'applications' tag.